# Is it possible to expose Twitter's Finatra admin pages (port 9990) on the main service port?

Tags: scala, twitter, finagle, twitter-finagle

We are working on a service using Twitter's Finatra. The main web services are exposed in port 8080 (using `override def defaultFinatraHttpPort = ":8080"`). Finatra exposes Finagle's Http Admin interface automatically on port 9000. Is it possible to instruct it to expose the `/admin/*` endpoints on the main application port (i.e. 8080)?

I've tried overwriting the '`adminPort`' var, however Finatra will try to create another Http listener on that port, which will fail because there is one already created. What I'm trying to do is to link the admin controllers to the main Http listener, so that everything is accessible from one single http port.

Comment: why? seperating that two services provides better access control. if you need to expose them on same address etc. you should let them listen to ports on localhost then create a reverse proxy using apache, ngix etc.

Comment: @HüseyinZengin: regarding 'why': unfortunately, it is an infrastructure requirement of our PaaS provider and something outside of our control. Rather that adding more processes (proxies, etc.) to the overall architecture, I'm curious if this is possible using just Finatra. Out-of-the-box, Finatra will expose any controller endpoint starting with "/admin" in the admin port, automatically... so I'd like to thing it can do the inverse.

Comment: It seems impossible but you can disable the admin server.  http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/build-new-http-server/